# How to place Find Results window to the right of text window?

Tags: notepad++, find

My **Find Results** widow is always opened and **docked** and is seen under editing text file. Since strings are often short than I want both text and **Find Results** window to be high (but narrower).

How to *place* **Find Results** widow to the right of text window?

I've tried to move Find Results widow but the only result is undoking and becoming separate popup window; plus a time to return to starting better state.

Answer (score 0):

- Click on the top of the result window
- Keep the button pressed
- Move to the right side of the main text window (until the cursor is inside the right scroller)
- Release the button
- It's done.

Comment: **Can't** move it to the right edge: it stops moving long before.
Then **how** can I move it to the edge?

Comment: **Have done it!** but only after closing **Document switcher** window: usage of **Document switcher** was the trouble  that disabled me to move **FRw** to the right edge.